# jQuery: Get each checked radio button and append its datasrc value

Tags: jquery, append, each

I am having a problem when trying to use each() twice.

I have a list of radio checked buttons of which each has a datasrc of a website.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" checked datasrc="www.john.com" id="John">John<br/>
<input type="radio" checked datasrc="www.maria.com" id="Maria">Maria<br/>
<input type="radio" datasrc="www.joe.com" id="Joe">Joe<br/>​
```

I want to retrieve each checked radio button so I do this:

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){

var name = $(this).attr("id");


    if($("[id="+name+"]:checked").length == 1)
    {
        var src = $('#' + name).attr("datasrc")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

      console.log(name);
      console.log(src);                        

    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
});
```

Now when I retrieve every checked radio button, I want to append it with id its id and for value, its datasrc. For example:

```
<div id="John">www.john.com</div>
<div id="Maria">www.maria.com</div>
```

When I tried using each again I get manage to get it printed but several times. For example john will print 4 times and maria will print 5 times (the amount of the id).

For example:

```
$("input:radio").each(function () {

   var name = $(this).attr("id");

   if ($("[id=" + name + "]:checked").length == 1) {
      var src = $('#' + name).attr("datasrc")

      var html = "";
      for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
         html += "<div id='" + name + "'>" + src + "</div>"
      }

      $("body").append(html);


   }

});
```

Will print:

```
www.john.com
www.john.com
www.john.com
www.john.com
www.maria.com
www.maria.com
www.maria.com
www.maria.com
www.maria.com
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you're nesting a for loop inside each so the results of the for loop run as many times as the each loop...You don't need the for loop though, a simple array and and `each()` will work:

**Edit:** Made it a function so you can use it at any time.

```
var getUrls = function () {

    var urls = [];

    $('input:radio').each(function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.attr('id'),
            url = $this.attr('datasrc');

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            urls.push('<div class="' + id + '">' + url + '</div>');
        }

    });

    return urls;

};

$('body').append(getUrls().join(''));
```

Comment: Works great. You need to change src with url thought. Thanks

Comment: I would use a class tho like suggested below

Comment: You'd have to provide some other ID for the generated DIV otherwise they will be duplicate with the radio IDs.

Comment: I will never be using same ID thus I dont need to provide class. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I solved your problem http://jsfiddle.net/3nvcj/

```
$(function() {

    $(':checked').each(function(index, element) {

        $('#result').append($('<div>').attr('id', $(element).attr('id')).text($(element).attr('datasrc')));
    });
});
```

Comment: I love simple and clever solutions!

Answer (score 1):

I think your script could be overly simplified like this:

```
$("input:radio").each(function () {

    // save for re-use
    var $this = $(this);

    // no need for jquery for javascript properties
    // 'this' is the DOM element and has a 'checked' property
    if (this.checked) {
        var src = $this.attr('datasrc');
        // you'd have to prefix the generated DIV id
        // otherwise you'll end up with duplicate IDs
        $('body').append("<div id='div" + this.id + "'>" + src + "</div>");
    }

});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/9YCjD/)**

Answer (score 0):

"Amount of id" makes me prick my ears. Each id may only be once on every page. If you use the same id on more than one element, the markup will be illegal.

Comment: I will use it once lol. Name it class, makes no difference to me since I'm the one creating the markup.

Comment: Currently you are creating DIVs with the same id as the corresponding radio button, and this is illegal!

Comment: Yes in my real-life example, the radio buttons are in a completely different page, passed into DB and retrieved in other page with the corresponding ID.